# Why is the object move arrows no longer fixated to it?

Tags: objects

not sure what I did but when selecting the move tool the arrows around the object popup, however when I move the object the arrows themselves stay fixated. I would like the arrows to be fixed on the object itself like the default setting. Any idea how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: You assigned the 3D cursor as the Pivot Point. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/scene_layout/object/editing/transform/control/pivot_point/index.html

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @FFeller solution in the comments I assigned the 3D cursor as the pivot point.

[Docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/scene_layout/object/editing/transform/control/pivot_point/index.html)